# Calling parent class function before executing every child class function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, overriding, python-unittest, python-class

Here is an idea of the code

File 1

```
class MyParentClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUpClass(self):
        # SuperClass is already defined in the file
        obj = SuperClass()
        self.exp_fn = obj.create_exp_fn()

    # This doesn't work
    def setUp(self):
        # sets up app to open the screen on which tests run (~100 lines)
```

File 2

```
from File1 import MyParentClass
class MyChildClass(MyParentClass):

    def test_func_1(self):
        # Start execution of its test
        self.exp_fn.run_an_attribute()


    def test_func_2(self):
        # Start execution of its test
        self.exp_fn.run_another_attribute()
```

I have several functions in `MyChildClass` and several files containing classes like `MyChildClass` which inherits `unittest.TestCase`

I want `setUp` to be called before executing any function of classes like `MyChildClass` but I don't want to individually decorate each function of `MyChildClass` or use the same 100 line `setUp()` function of unittest in all the files of `MyChildClass`. It should be present in MyParentClass as shown above

To run the tests I need to setUp the app such as open a specific screen, login and open another set of windows before a test can start. Or else the test won't find the element its looking for coz the app wouldn't be on the desired screen.
And the tests start from outside the app always

Is there a way to achieve the same functionality of `setUp()` following the above conditions. I went through the source code of `run()` in unittest where they use a contextmanager to implement `setUp()` but didn't quite get it

Would be highly obliged if anyone can suggest a solution... Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. - why you can't use `setUp` or `setUpClass` in your base class? What is `func_1` - is it called by the tests? You haven't shown any tests here... Maybe you can explain what should happen if a a test is run.

Comment: I have many files which import `MyParentClass` and test different portions of an app.  The `setUp` function is nearly 100 lines long and almost same for all. So I dont wan't to put it in every file to reduce redundancy. I have used `setUpClass` but it executes only once when the test suite class is initialised (which it should). I have shown an abridged version due to privacy norms of my employer... Sorry

Comment: So `setUp` is _nearly_ the same for all, so why don't you factor out the different part(s) and implement only these in the subclasses? Maybe I still haven't got your problem...

Comment: To run the tests I need to setUp the app such as open a specific screen, login and open another set of windows before a test can start. Or else the test won't find the element its looking for coz the app wouldn't be on the desired screen

Comment: So you can't do that `setUp` in the test class itself? Do you have to start the test process itself from outside?

Comment: Yes. Test starts from outside always. I can do `setUp` inside class but that would make the files have redundant code... something which I want to avoid